# Converting a pickle dictionary to DataFrame for calculating median

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary

I am new to using Pandas or other data analysis libraries and needed some help in converting my data into a DataFrame to begin doing computations on it. 
My pickle data is a dictionary of type:

```
{'/AcroForm': ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], 
'xref': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1'], 
'obj': ['8', '8', '8', '9', '9', '24', '24', '8', '9', '8', '24', '24', '24', '24', '24', '8', '3', '0', '8', '8', '8'], '/JS': ['2', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '2', '2', '0', '1', '2'], 
'stream': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '5', '5', '1', '1', '1', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1'], 
'endobj': ['8', '8', '8', '9', '8', '24', '24', '8', '9', '8', '24', '24', '24', '23', '24', '8', '3', '0', '8', '8', '8'], 
'/OpenAction': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2'], 
'/JavaScript': ['2', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1'],
'endstream': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '5', '5', '1', '1', '1', '5', '5', '5', '5', '4', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1'], 
'/Page': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1'], 
'/RichMedia': ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], 
'startxref': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1'], 
'/JBIG2Decode': ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], 
'/EmbeddedFile': ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], 
'/Encrypt': ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], 
'/AA': ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], 
'/XFA': ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], 
'/ObjStm': ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], 
'/Launch': ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], 
'trailer': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']}
```

My use-case is to basically calculate a mean and median of this dictionary object.
Based on some reading, I figured out that `Python Pandas` can be helpful for my case. What I understood is that I will have to convert the pickle file to a DataFrame first before I can use the mean and median functions on it. 
I am looking for the best possible approach and open to implement different approaches as well (should be in python).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
In [162]: pd.DataFrame(d).agg(['mean','median'])
Out[162]:
        /AA  /AcroForm  /EmbeddedFile  /Encrypt  /JBIG2Decode           /JS   /JavaScript  /Launch  /ObjStm   /OpenAction  \
mean    0.0        0.0            0.0       0.0           0.0  9.524286e+18  9.524286e+18      0.0      0.0  5.290953e+18
median  0.0        0.0            0.0       0.0           0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00      0.0      0.0  1.000000e+00

               /Page  /RichMedia  /XFA        endobj     endstream           obj     startxref        stream       trailer  \
mean    5.291005e+18         0.0   0.0  4.233250e+26  5.291215e+18  4.233297e+26  5.291005e+18  5.291215e+18  5.291005e+18
median  1.000000e+00         0.0   0.0  8.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  8.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00

                xref
mean    5.291005e+18
median  1.000000e+00
```

where `d` is a given dictionary...

**Demo:**

```
In [165]: pickle.dump(d, open('d:/temp/a.pckl', 'wb'))

In [166]: with open('d:/temp/a.pckl', 'rb') as f:
     ...:     df = pd.DataFrame(pickle.load(f)).agg(['mean','median'])
     ...:

In [167]: df
Out[167]:
        /AA  /AcroForm  /EmbeddedFile  /Encrypt  /JBIG2Decode           /JS   /JavaScript  /Launch  /ObjStm   /OpenAction  \
mean    0.0        0.0            0.0       0.0           0.0  9.524286e+18  9.524286e+18      0.0      0.0  5.290953e+18
median  0.0        0.0            0.0       0.0           0.0  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00      0.0      0.0  1.000000e+00

               /Page  /RichMedia  /XFA        endobj     endstream           obj     startxref        stream       trailer  \
mean    5.291005e+18         0.0   0.0  4.233250e+26  5.291215e+18  4.233297e+26  5.291005e+18  5.291215e+18  5.291005e+18
median  1.000000e+00         0.0   0.0  8.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  8.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00

                xref
mean    5.291005e+18
median  1.000000e+00
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I guess I can read my pickle file to an object and pass it as dictonary.